# Date/Time format conversion to 4-byte long

Tags: c#, c++, date, datetime, time

I am using a program that outputs time like "2:30PM", which I like to add date to it (e.g. "04/09/2015 14:30") and ultimately convert it to a 4-byte long. If I code this in C++ or C#, how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Usually Stack Overflow isn't right place to dump requirements but **specific problems with EXISTING code**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. Very simple:

```
string time = "2:30pm";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(time).ToUniversalTime();
DateTime orig = DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
long ldt = (long)((dt - orig).TotalSeconds);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

In C++14, using [this library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), you could easily store this as a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` with:

```
using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;
system_clock::time_point tp = sys_days(apr/9/2015) + 14h + 30min;
```

A `system_clock::time_point` is likely to be stored as an 8-byte signed integer, instead of a 4-byte integer.  If the 4-byte issue is really important you could create a sibling of `system_clock::time_point` like this:

```
using TimePoint = time_point<system_clock, duration<int32_t, ratio<60>>>;
TimePoint tp = sys_days(apr/9/2015) + 14h + 30min;
```

This `TimePoint` would still be interoperable with `system_clock::time_point`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in C#.

`Date.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0))`

or

`TimeOfDay.Add(new TimepSpan(0,0,0))`